# Need assistance editing drop down list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Please accept my apologies if this has been addressed before.  I have very little code experience and I'm trying to edit a project that was originally created (but never implemented) by an employee who is no longer employed with our agency.

The issue I have is the asp.net page I'm trying to edit has two drop down lists that need to be edited.  They currently display hours in half-hour increments from 6:00AM to 7:00PM.  I actually need the lists to increment every 15 minutes.  The problem is that I am unable to find where the lists are populated. I have been through every ASP.NET page within the site directory and have come up empty handed.  I thought it might be in the code behind file for the page, but there are no code behind files at all.  If anyone can assist with this I would be greatly appreciative.  The sample code of the first list is below if it helps.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLeaveStart" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!"
                                            InitialValue="Choose a time" ControlToValidate="ddlLeaveStart" CssClass="failureNotification" />
```

Thanks

Comment: You should search the project for `ddlLeaveStart`, the ID of the dropdown. It is being populated with options somewhere in code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a project file to search. There is nothing in the root directory with a *.*proj extension.  I have .aspx, .dll, .xml, .js, and web.config.  After searching through the entire site for that ID, it comes up in multiple places but nowhere does it appear that the list is defined.

Comment: I found this under object browser:

protected virtual System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList ddlLeaveStart {protected  get; protected  set; }
    Member of eLeave.EnterLeave

Comment: So you have no *.cs files?

Comment: No .cs files at all. Is there a way to use the existing ID and manually input the list items while bypassing the original control values?  I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: So you do not have source code? You will need to decompile then which is advanced and error prone. You might possibly see if there is a stored proc in the database that is used to populate.

Comment: It really sounds like you need help from someone inside your agency. Where is the source code? Is it checked into a repository somewhere? Do you have access to that? Without the source, it's almost fruitless to try & proceed here.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  It turns out there was a table in the database with a non-descript name that held the values for the list.  I apologize for the unnecessary post, but I'm a little out of my element here.  Good news is I was able to accomplish what I was wanting to do.